# how to give permission to web server in windows 7 to write to a network folder

Tags: php, networking, phpexcel

so my script is running in my localhost(pc1) and i am trying to save an excel file using phpexcel in a network folder `(\\pc2\c$\myfolder)` but it gives me an error saying that i dont have permission in that particular folder eventhough i have a full access. I can manually create, edit or deleta a file in that folder.

error msg:

```
Warning: fopen(\\pc2\c$\myfolder\12122014.xls) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\receivables\PHPExcel\Shared\OLE\PPS\Root.php on line 90

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'Can't open \\pc2\c$\myfolder\12122014.xls. It may be in use or protected.' in C:\wamp\www\receivables\PHPExcel\Shared\OLE\PPS\Root.php:93 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\receivables\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel5.php(226): PHPExcel_Shared_OLE_PPS_Root->save('\\ipcsvs001\c...') #1 C:\wamp\www\receivables\index.php(241): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5->save('\\ipcsvs001\c...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\receivables\PHPExcel\Shared\OLE\PPS\Root.php on line 93
```

note: i am using wamp server(not sure if this matters)

Comment: make sure, that the user of IIS / Apache and or php has rights to use the share and has write-rights

Comment: my user account have full access in the destination folder, but still no luck to save file.

Comment: Your user account might, but IIS does not run by default as your user account, it runs as a local service account. Check in task manager what user account it is.

Comment: sir i cant find it in task manager...i am using wamp..so it means i need to make the user of apache to use my user account???

Comment: when i `echo exec('whoami');` - `nt authority\system`